# how i can fix following nullrefernce ? and also how can I turn off nullrefernce (from <propertygroup>)?

Tags: c#

```
public class BlockChain
{   
   public IList<Block>Chain{ get; set; }
}
```

**Non-nullable property 'Chain' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.**

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what project you are writing but you could do:

1. add `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in .csproj file
2. add `#nullable disable` in class
3. set `Chain` as `public IList<Block> Chain{ get; set; } = new NameOfClassThatImplementsInterface();` (recommended)
4. set `Chain` as `public IList<Block>? Chain{ get; set; }`